# How to use countif, sumif across two sheets where the logical test is an equivalency?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, countif

I am building a simple sum sheet that relies on a conditional but I can't seem to get COUNTIF/SUMIF to work for me.

To sum, I have two sheets, one with a few hundred lines of records including an vendor ID# (Sheet1|2!A:A), fees (B:B), and hours (all of which may be duplicate, sorted by vendor ID#). On the second sheet, I have taken the vendor ID#s, removed duplicates, and would like the remainder of the sheet be a summation of the records from the first sheet.

Specifically, I was expecting a formula something like this to work:

- `=SUMIF(Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A:A)` (to find total fees, hours)
- `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A:A)` (to find frequency of vendor ID in rows)

Both of these are only returning zero once they're entered, however. Basically, I want it to sum the fees column (B:B) from the first sheet on the second sheet, wherever the logical test comes back true that the vendor ID on sheet 1 is the same as the vendor ID on sheet 2 (`...1!A=...2!A`)

Comment: I have verified that the equivalency could work (i.e. the data is stored correctly and can return a TRUE in 1!A2=2!A2); I seem to be incorrectly inputting the series into the test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. For SUMIF you want the Range to be `Sheet1!A:A`, Criteria to be `A1` (if that is where the single instance of the vendor ID# is held) and the Sum_range to be `Sheet1!B:B`.

Example `Sheet2` (inside box) below where the formulae are the contents of `Row6`.

[image]